# If $a=b+c$ , $a^2$ is an integer, can $b^2$ or $c^2$ or both be irrational?

Tags: rationality-testing

Say, $a=b+c$,
$a$ may be rational or irrational.
However, the **constraint on $a$ is that $a^2$ is an integer**.
b>0 , c>0 which means a>0.
Wanted to confirm that either $b^2$ or $c^2$ or both can't be irrational.

I reasoned like this :
$a^2 =(b+c)^2$
or $a^2=b^2+2bc+c^2\tag{1}$
Since *the sum of a rational and irrational number is irrational* (is it correct?), and the
left hand side of $(1)$ is $a^2$ which is an integer, i.e., a rational number, neither $b^2$ nor $c^2$ can be irrational. For that matter, $2bc$ can't be irrational either.
Conclusion: $a^2, b^2$ and $bc$ are rational numbers.

If any of my friends in this forum can help me confirm that above conclusion is correct, I will be grateful.

Comment: $1=\sin^2 (1)+\cos^2 (1)$.

Comment: I understand that you have a=1 , what is b ? What is c?
Since, $a^2=b^2+c^2+2bc$ , in the above counter-example, what is 2bc?

 I apologize for missing these constraints :  b>0 and c>0. In that case, is the conclusion valid that b^2,c^2 and bc must be rational.
Can you provide some counterexamples involving non-transcedental functions?
I have meanwhile edited my earlier question.
Will wait for your further feedback.
Thanks

Comment: Obviously you can do it with algebraic numbers.  Just try.  $1=(\sqrt[3] 2-1)+(2-\sqrt[3] 2)$.  You should have no difficulty producing examples.

Comment: Great.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head, I could think of b = 2^(1/4) and c = -2^(1/4) as counterexamples.

Comment: Excellent counter-example!! 

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thatnks a lot, it is an eye opener. 
However, I apologize for missing these constraints also. Both b>0 and c>0. In that case, is the conclusion valid that b^2,c^2 and bc must be rational.